# GridView don't set NumColumns correctly (only contains images)

Tags: android, layout, gridview

I'm trying to implement an own-gallery for my application. I've some categories and each of this categories has it own GridView of Images. They are implemented in code-behind and added to my LinearLayout.

I've the following problem: In each row is space for 4 images on my device. Some of this galleries contains more than 4 images but the GridView doesn't show them in another row (so they seem to be invisible for the user)

I've tried the following sourcecode:

```
GridView gridView = new GridView(this);
gridView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
gridView.setNumColumns(GridView.AUTO_FIT);
gridView.setVerticalSpacing(10);// TODO check if 10dp
gridView.setHorizontalSpacing(10);
gridView.setColumnWidth(90);
gridView.setStretchMode(GridView.STRETCH_COLUMN_WIDTH);
gridView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

I thought "setNumColums" - AUTO_FIT - Value handles my problem, but it doesn't.

I hope you can understand my problem :)
Sorry for my bad englisch.

Merry Christmas!